# QtWebKit Manager

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I've been asked to research a way to manage a QTWebKit module outside of QT. The idea is to use QTWebKit as an interface(GUI) for an application. The desired (Manager) should work as a communication mean between the GUI and the main application which is written in C++.

The manager should be designed in a way that it can produce java queries and handle events from the GUI itself and updates the pages according to user interactions and/or message updates from the main application.

We've considered the option of doing an internal webserver to be somewhat slow and frankly I am not sure how to or where to begin the design from as almost all of the examples associated with QTWebKit are merely simple web browsers.

If someone can point me to an online article or example that implements or discusses something similar to what I'm talking about, I would be much grateful.

And please note that the matter at hand is not how QTWebKit manipulates and updates HTML pages, the problem is how it can communicate with other applications and how other application can send information to QTWebKit

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Qt supports D-BUS, but only on unix.

Comment: Your use case looks quite strange. If you need to update dynamically web pages, server technology looks like a good choice, no ? And QtWebkit is already in C++ so I don't see the point of separating it from a C++ application.

Answer (score 2):

Shared Memory. In Qt you can use QSharedMemory. If you don't want to introduce Qt dependency in your other C++ app. I suggest you create a shared memory communication as a seperate application and load it as a process to communicate.